# JList - get number of selected elements in multi-select list

Tags: java, arrays, jlist

How do i get the number of selected elements from my jlist? So that i can create an int[] array and add the selected indices to this array.

Comment: Does [JList.getSelectedIndices()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndices%28%29) not suffice, it yields the `int[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JList.getSelectedIndices().length would give you the array length  :) Refer Javadocs mate